# Find value of one column within another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-07', '2020-08-08'],
                   'end': ['2020-08-03', '', '', '2020-08-06', '', '2020-08-08', '', ''],
                   'score': [74, 81, 38, 49, 79, 17, 53, 69]})

df

         start         end  score
0   2020-08-01  2020-08-03     74
1   2020-08-02                 81
2   2020-08-03                 38
3   2020-08-04  2020-08-06     49
4   2020-08-05                 79
5   2020-08-06  2020-08-08     17
6   2020-08-07                 53
7   2020-08-08                 69
```

that I need to add a new column in which the row is marked as `1` when `end` date is found in `start`, that is:

```python
         start         end  score  mark
0   2020-08-01  2020-08-03     74
1   2020-08-02                 81
2   2020-08-03                 38     1
3   2020-08-04  2020-08-06     49
4   2020-08-05                 79
5   2020-08-06  2020-08-08     17     1
6   2020-08-07                 53
7   2020-08-08                 69     1
```

What's a good `pandas` solution to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['mark']=np.where(df.start.isin(df.end),'1',' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with

```
s = df['start'].isin(df['end']).astype(int)
df['New'] = s.where(s==1 ,'')
```

Comment: Notice if you would like the other row just 0 I will just do df['New']=s, since this is better do not create mixed type columns

Comment: You got here before me, I wonder what the cost of 'where' is as compared to normal dataframe slicing and enlargement:

df.loc[df[df['end'].isin(df['start'])].index, 'newcol'] = 1

Comment: @deefunkt where can assign the not selected value with ' ' :-)